Unresolved reference: multiplatformResources in Kotlin Multiplatform Project using MOKO Resources
`I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project and trying to integrate MOKO Resources. I followed the installation instructions according to the official documentation, but I'm encountering an "Unresolved reference: multiplatformResources" error when trying to configure the plugin in my build.gradle.kts.
Here is an excerpt from my build.gradle.kts:`
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.mokoMultiplatformResources)
}

kotlin {
    wasmJs {
        moduleName = "composeApp"
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                outputFileName = "composeApp.js"
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.24.1")
            api("dev.icerock.moko:resources-compose:0.24.1")
        }
    }
}

multiplatformResources {
    resourcesPackage.set("org.example.library")
    resourcesClassName.set("SharedRes")
    resourcesVisibility.set(MRVisibility.Internal)
    iosBaseLocalizationRegion.set("en")
    iosMinimalDeploymentTarget.set("11.0")
}





Error Message:
Unresolved reference: multiplatformResources

Attempted Solutions:
I ensured all dependencies are correctly defined in libs.versions.toml and settings.gradle.kts.
I reviewed the MOKO Resources documentation to make sure I followed the steps correctly.
Can someone help understand why multiplatformResources is not recognized and how I can fix this issue?
